# Repeating a function over many variables

Tags: r

I need to repeat a function over 43 variables. More specifically, I am running a non-parametric repeated measures test on my data. This should result in two final data sets - one data set with the overall test stats for each variable and a second which contains specific tests for each pair of times to show where the differences are.

I have created my list of variables for looping and the function but am unsure how to progress to make the function run over all variables.

I would be most grateful for any help with:
1. Running my function over each variable
2. Combining the the results for each variable into two data frames (one for overall tests and the second for specific time differences as highlighted in the code).

Many thanks in advance!

Here is my data:

```
> dput(junk)
structure(list(Patient = c("TLA001", "TLA001", "TLA001", "TLA001", 
"TLA001", "TLA001", "TLA002", "TLA002", "TLA002", "TLA002", "TLA002", 
"TLA003", "TLA003", "TLA003", "TLA003", "TLA003", "TLA003", "TLA004", 
"TLA004", "TLA004", "TLA004", "TLA004", "TLA004", "TLA005", "TLA005", 
"TLA005", "TLA005", "TLA005", "TLA005", "TLA006", "TLA006", "TLA006", 
"TLA006", "TLA006", "TLA006", "TLA006", "TLA008", "TLA008", "TLA008", 
"TLA008", "TLA008", "TLA008", "TLA009", "TLA009", "TLA009", "TLA009", 
"TLA009", "TLA009", "TLA010", "TLA010", "TLA010", "TLA010", "TLA010", 
"TLA010", "TLA011", "TLA011", "TLA011", "TLA011", "TLA011", "TLA011", 
"TLA012", "TLA012", "TLA012", "TLA012", "TLA012", "TLA012", "TLA012", 
"TLA013", "TLA013", "TLA013", "TLA013", "TLA013", "TLA013", "TLA013", 
"TLA014", "TLA014", "TLA014", "TLA014", "TLA015", "TLA015", "TLA015", 
"TLA015", "TLA015", "TLA015"), Night = c("TLA -3", "TLA -2", 
"TLA -1", "TLA 1", "TLA 2", "TLA 3", "TLA -3", "TLA -2", "TLA -1", 
"TLA 1", "TLA 2", "TLA -3", "TLA -2", "TLA -1", "TLA 1", "TLA 2", 
"TLA 3", "TLA -3", "TLA -2", "TLA -1", "TLA 1", "TLA 2", "TLA 3", 
"TLA -3", "TLA -2", "TLA -1", "TLA 1", "TLA 2", "TLA 3", "TLA -3", 
"TLA -2", "TLA -1", "TLA 1", "TLA 2", "TLA 3", "TLA 4", "TLA -3", 
"TLA -2", "TLA -1", "TLA 1", "TLA 2", "TLA 3", "TLA -3", "TLA -2", 
"TLA -1", "TLA 1", "TLA 2", "TLA 3", "TLA -3", "TLA -2", "TLA -1", 
"TLA 1", "TLA 2", "TLA 3", "TLA -3", "TLA -2", "TLA -1", "TLA 1", 
"TLA 2", "TLA 3", "TLA -3", "TLA -2", "TLA -1", "TLA 1", "TLA 2", 
"TLA 3", "TLA 4", "TLA -3", "TLA -2", "TLA -1", "TLA 1", "TLA 2", 
"TLA 3", "TLA 4", "TLA -3", "TLA -2", "TLA -1", "TLA 1", "TLA -3", 
"TLA -2", "TLA -1", "TLA 1", "TLA 2", "TLA 3"), var = c(0.1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 2.8, 0.2, 0.3, 0, 0.4, 0.3, 0, 2.2, 
1.1, 0.6, 2.1, 1.4, 1.7, 0.9, 0.3, 0.3, 0, 1, 0, 0.3, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0, 0.4, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1.1, 0.8, 0, 0, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0.9, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 
1, 0.9, 0, 0, 0, 0.3, 0.3, 0, 0, 1.2, 0.9, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), SF_Cluster = c("Responder", "Responder", "Responder", 
"Responder", "Responder", "Responder", "Non-responder", "Non-responder", 
"Non-responder", "Non-responder", "Non-responder", "Responder", 
"Responder", "Responder", "Responder", "Responder", "Responder", 
"Responder", "Responder", "Responder", "Responder", "Responder", 
"Responder", "Responder", "Responder", "Responder", "Responder", 
"Responder", "Responder", "Non-responder", "Non-responder", "Non-responder", 
"Non-responder", "Non-responder", "Non-responder", "Non-responder", 
"Responder", "Responder", "Responder", "Responder", "Responder", 
"Responder", "Non-responder", "Non-responder", "Non-responder", 
"Non-responder", "Non-responder", "Non-responder", "Responder", 
"Responder", "Responder", "Responder", "Responder", "Responder", 
"Responder", "Responder", "Responder", "Responder", "Responder", 
"Responder", "Non-responder", "Non-responder", "Non-responder", 
"Non-responder", "Non-responder", "Non-responder", "Non-responder", 
"Responder", "Responder", "Responder", "Responder", "Responder", 
"Responder", "Responder", "Non-responder", "Non-responder", "Non-responder", 
"Non-responder", "Responder", "Responder", "Responder", "Responder", 
"Responder", "Responder")), row.names = c(NA, -84L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Patient = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Night = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), var = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), SF_Cluster = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), class = "col_spec"))
```

Here is my code:

```
names(junk)
varlist=names(junk)[5:9]

library("nparLD")

nonparLD=function(var, data=junk) {
  boxplot(var  ~ Night, data = data, lwd = 2, xlab = "time", ylab="N",
        font.lab = 2, cex.lab = 2, main = "Box Plots: var  ")

ex.f1np <- nparLD(var  ~ T, data = data, subject = "id",
                  description = FALSE)
plot(ex.f1np,main = "Relative Effects: var  " )
summary(ex.f1np)

#Data frame 1: Overall test result
r_var=rbind(ex.f1np$ANOVA.test,ex.f1np$Wald.test )
rownames(r_var)=c("varAT","var_WT")


#Data frame 2: which time differences are significant?

m1_2 <- which(((data$T == 1) + (data$T == 2)) == 1)
m1_3 <- which(((data$T == 1) + (data$T == 3)) == 1)
m1_4<- which(((data$T == 1) + (data$T == 4)) == 1)
m1_5<- which(((data$T == 1) + (data$T == 5)) == 1)
m1_6<- which(((data$T == 1) + (data$T == 6)) == 1)


ex.f1np1_2 <- nparLD(var ~ T, data = data[m1_2,], subject = "id",
                     description = FALSE)

ex.f1np1_3 <- nparLD(var ~ T, data = data[m1_3,], subject = "id",
                     description = FALSE)

ex.f1np1_4 <- nparLD(var ~ T, data = data[m1_4,], subject = "id",
                     description = FALSE)

ex.f1np1_5 <- nparLD(var ~ T, data = data[m1_5,], subject = "id",
                     description = FALSE)

ex.f1np1_2 <- nparLD(var ~ T, data = data[m1_2,], subject = "id",
                     description = FALSE)

ex.f1np1_6 <- nparLD(var ~ T, data = data[m1_6,], subject = "id",
                     description = FALSE)


summary(ex.f1np1_2)
summary(ex.f1np1_3)
summary(ex.f1np1_4)
summary(ex.f1np1_5)
summary(ex.f1np1_6)


#Data set for test stats
r_varT=rbind(ex.f1np1_2$ANOVA.test,ex.f1np1_2$Wald.test,
                      ex.f1np1_3$ANOVA.test,ex.f1np1_3$Wald.test,
                      ex.f1np1_4$ANOVA.test,ex.f1np1_4$Wald.test,
                      ex.f1np1_5$ANOVA.test,ex.f1np1_5$Wald.test,
                      ex.f1np1_6$ANOVA.test,ex.f1np1_6$Wald.test)

#Data set for time differences for each var
r_varT=t(r_varT)
colnames(r_varT)=c("AT12","WT12","AT13","WT13","AT14","WT14","AT15","WT15","AT16","WT16" )
rownames(r_varT)=c("varS", "varDF","varP")
}
```

Comment: Apologies - updated.

Comment: You want something like: apply(junk, 2, nonparLD)

Comment: Thank you for reading my post. I got an error message: ```` Error in x[floor(d)] + x[ceiling(d)] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator````

Comment: ah yes, I guess that will be because of the mixed types in your DF i.e. you have string columns and you can't do a boxplot of a string col by night if that makes sense. My question is then, presumably you only want to run the code for numeric columns, is that correct?

Comment: if the answer is yes then you want to subset the numeric cols using something like `numcols <- unlist(lapply(junk, is.numeric))` and then do `apply(junk[,numcols], 2, nonparLD)`

Comment: Great suggestion. I substituted using `varlist` instead of `numcols`. `apply(junk[,varlist], 2, nonparLD)`. I get the error  ` Error in model.frame.default(formula, data) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'T') ` . Not sure why as each id has the same number of  `T` .